# aimerais / voudrais, prendre / avoir

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I am in the process of trying to learn French and have been using Google translate for some assistance and on occasion an perplexed by some of the results given.

Please, can someone tell me which of these sentences are grammatically correct as all three give me the same result in English?

- J'aimerais prendre un café avec vous
- je voudrais prendre un café avec vous
- je voudrais avoir un café avec vous

Answer (score 1):

**The first two sentences have the same meaning**. **The third sentence is completly different**.

Despite this, there is a small subtle difference for the first two sentences.

> J'aimerais prendre un café avec vous. -> I would like to drink/have a coffee with you.
>
> Je voudrais prendre un café avec vous. -> I would want to drink/have a coffe with you.

The first sentence is more polite than the second because it expresses the intention :  *I **would like** to have a coffee with you, only **if you agree**.* The second one is still polite too, but the feeling could be different, it is a **"little"** bit stronger (French advanced).

The last one is correct but it means something completly different :

> Je voudrais avoir un café avec vous. -> I would want to have my own cafe restaurant with you (building).

The sentence is correct too. But it does not mean what you expect. *Since you are not 100% francophone, people will still understand that you want to drink coffe and you will not open a coffe shop.*

Comment: Thank you for the response and answers. This is a great platform and I will definitely use it more often.

Comment: @SiNe1 I suggest you wait a little to let people write other answers, but after that feel free to accept the answer that you're the most satisfied with.